# Unable to connect to oracle database after installing the module

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I have successfully installed Oracledb module on my machine(Windows). But now I am not able to get the connection to my database.The method is not called I guess.Here's my code... 
Someone please help me out to get the connection to my database.

```
this.oracleConnect = function () {
   oracledb.getConnection({
        user: "user",
        password: "password",
        connectString: "url"
    },

    function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Database connected");
            connection.execute(
                "UPDATE employee set sal= 4400 where EMP_ID = 428949",
                function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        //console.error(err); 
                        return;
                    } else {
                        //console.log(result.rows);
                    }
                });
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you've defined a function but not invoked it.

Where do you call oracleConnect?